# Model likes, dislikes and comments in a SQL databse

Tags: database-design

I'm now creating a website similar to Reddit.
Here, a **user** can write a **post**, while other users, including the *writer*, can **comment** and/or **up/downvote (1 or -1)** the post.

And to store the necessary data, I designed the following *SQL model*, however as this is my first time designing an *SQL model*, I'm not certain if I did well, so I would like to ask if my model is good or not.

By the way, I tried to normalize it to the ***third normal form***.

```
USERS = (email, familyName, givenName, Password);
POSTS = (Id_posts, #email, postText, postDate);
TO_COMMENT = (#email, #Id_posts, commentText, commentDate);
TO_VOTE = (#email, #Id_posts, vote);
```

I thank in advance anyone who will take the time to advise me.

P.S: For the total score of the vote, I thought about using a ***sum()***, that's why it's not divided in two *(upvote and downvote)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a few thoughts:

> USERS = (email, familyName, givenName, Password);

I would strongly recommend adding artificial Id column as primary key for USERS. (Same as you already have *Id_posts* for POSTS.) While the email is surely going to be unique, it would also mean that it is going to be unreasonably difficult to change (because it is going to be in all the tables over the whole database). If it is just an another field, you can change it easily.

> POSTS = (Id_posts, #email, postText, postDate);
> TO_COMMENT = (#email, #Id_posts, commentText, commentDate);

Can you comment and vote on comments themself? If so, then I would suggest that POSTS and TO_COMMENT are the same thing, simply differentiated by the fact that comments are responses to post. Therefore I would merge these two tables and simply add ParentPost_ID foreign key referencing back to the table for the parent post. (And your posts would be simply posts `WHERE ParentPostID IS NULL`.)

But this is debatable point. What you're doing here is certainly valid, especially if there is going to be difference between posts and comments.

> TO_COMMENT, TO_VOTE

Generally it is recommended to have nouns as table names. I. e. COMMENT, VOTE. It is usually more descriptive, because it's *objects* that are stored in the table, not *actions*.

Fix the email thing, but overall, I think your current design is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why trying to reinvent the wheel.

1. Download the [StackOverflow database](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/10/how-to-download-the-stack-overflow-database-via-bittorrent/): it has all the tables you need and even more; it has been largely used and probably has already faced all the architectural problems that you are going to face. It already has the tables you want:

[image]

2. Now [delete all the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687575/delete-all-data-in-sql-server-database) into it.

Done! You have a future proof database.